# Missing characters in string java

Tags: java, tcp, server, tokenize, stringbuilder

I'm trying to implement a java server with http frames, I have a couple of URI's : /login.jsp and /logout.jsp that are found in the Request URi of the http format.

When I send the logout request to the Server I send it with a header like so:

```
Cookie: user_auth="SomeCookie".
```

Here is the code:

```
public HttpMessage nextMessage() {
    if (!isAlive()) {
        try {
            throw new IOException("Tokenizer is Closed");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // Return String
    HttpMessage newMessage = null;
    String output = null;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        int c;

        while ((c = this.fInputStream.read()) != -1) {
            if (c == this.fDelimiter)
                break;
            else
                stringBuilder.append((char) c);
        }
        // Create an HttpMessage from the information received
        output = stringBuilder.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        this.fClosed = true;
        try {
            throw new IOException("Connection is Dead");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    newMessage = parseHttp(output);
    return newMessage;
}
```

The parseHttp method breaks the type, and headers apart.

But the problem is after sending the **login** action to the server, if I try send the **logout** action the parsed information stored in the string builder has missing characters(more specifically the RequestType, RequestURI and the HttpVersion ) are missing and only the header can be found.

In addition if I try to print each characters I receive from the inputStream at the time I see all the characters that are supposed to be in the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want the `break;` line and not a `continue;` break will cause the while loop to exit while using continue will simply skip the else and run the next iteration of the while loop.

Comment: Thank you ! though continue won't work here I got a hint to what might be the problem. The problem with my code was that the null character stayed in the inputStreamReader and the next time I tried reading from the stream the first character I received was the null character, though it is strange that I still could read the other characters until the next delimiter..

Answer (score 0):

Following code prints all the missing characters in a given string by removing duplicates.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MissChars
{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String str=sc.nextLine();
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
    char c[]=str.toCharArray();
    LinkedHashSet<Character> set=new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
    for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
      set.add(c[i]);
    for(char cc:set)
      sb.append(cc);
    String sss=new String(sb);
    char arr[]=sss.toCharArray();
    for(char i='a';i<='z';i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
        {
            if(i!=arr[j])
                count++;
            if(count==arr.length)
              System.out.print(i);
        }
        count=0;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Its a code to print all the missing characters in a given string by removing duplicates.Hope this code helps u..

Comment: You better write your comment in the answer! See my edit and delete your comment.